# How to wait for a promise to resolve before the next iteration in for loop

Tags: javascript, django, for-loop, promise

I have got two data tables I want to query some data from, so the way i thought about doing it is fetch url and based on a field from list, I do fetch(url) once more to get related data from another data table and I want to append them together to display on the browser. The issue here is that for loop iteration doesn't wait until the previous fetch is finished. I am using django_restframework, and it is me trying to fetch data by passing criteria(variables) through urls. can anyone help?

```
var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/creditor-detail/'+pmt_id+'/supplier/'+crm_spplier_id+'/'

var results = fetch(url)
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then(function(item){ 

        var list = item
        for (var i in list){

                    getCustomer(list[i].customer_id)
                    .then(function test(user) {
                    return user[0].customer_name
                   
                  });

                var spmt = `
                    <tr id="data-row-${i}">
                        <td>${list[i].po_no}</td>
                        <td>${list[i].amount}</td>                  
                        <td>${I want return value[user[0].customer_name]}</td>
                    </tr>
                `
                wrapper.innerHTML+= spmt
        }
      })





  function getCustomer(customer_id){
    var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/user-detail/'+customer_id+'/'

    var results = fetch(url)
                  .then((resp) => resp.json())
                  .then(function(item){

                      return item       
                  })
  return results
}
```

I have changed to:

```
    function test() {
      const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/creditor-detail/'+pmt_id+'/supplier/'+crm_supplier_id+'/'
      let promises = [];

      const results = fetch(url)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(function (item) {

        var list = item;
   
        for (var i in list) {
          promises.push(getCusotmer(list[i].customer_id));
          console.log(list[i].customer_id)

        }
      })
      
      Promise.all(promises)
          .then((results) => {
            console.log("All done", results);
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            
            console.log(err)
          });
    }
    
    


    function getCusotmer(customer_id) {
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/customer-detail/' + customer_id+ '/';
      fetch(url)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then((item) => resolve(item))
        .catch((err) => {

          console.log(err)
          
          reject(err)
        })
    })
  }

  test();
```

And the console looks like this:

All done []length: 0__proto__: Array(0)
1466
1663

I thought based on the promise logic, all done should have been read in the end, am I missing anything here?

Comment: Rewrite your code inside an `async` function using `await`.  Google those terms.  Don't use `.then`, it doesn't let you do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand the first time, but here I go.
The simple answer is "You can't do that", javascript works with an 'event loop', it's like a thread containing all the tasks javascript is going to do, when you use an asynchronous task like 'search' it escapes the 'event loop' for being asynchronous . But the 'for loop' is not asynchronous so it will be processed in the 'Event Loop'.
This means that 'fetch' will exit the 'Event Loop' and when its request is completed it will return to the 'Event Loop',  in this moment, the 'for loop' was terminate.

But don't worry, you can solve it, how? well, you can iterate the loop and save a new array of promise, await for all of them will complete and in this moment create your 'tr' row

Its an example with your code:
The first function could be like this:

```
const promises = [];
fetch(url)
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then((item) => {
    const list = item;
    for (let i in list) {
      promises.push(getCustomer(list[i].customer_id))
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then((resolveAllData) => {
      //Do all that you need with your data
      //Maybe you can use a for loop for iterate 'responseAllData
    });
  }).catch((err) => {
    //manage your err
  })
```

And the second function could be like this:

```
function getCustomer(customer_id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/user-detail/' + customer_id + '/';
    fetch(url)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then((item) => resolve(item))
      .catch((err) => {
         //manage your err
         reject(err)
      })
  })
}
```

A recommendation, learn how JavaScript works and its asynchronism, try not to use 'var', to get better performance and have no problems with scope

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It really helped me understand how promises work with javascript, just a quick question. so as suggested by you, I tried below code to see how it would come out, but I didn't see anything in the console. Do you have any idea as to what that would happen?         Promise.all(promises).then((resolveAllData) => {

          for (var x in resolveAllData ){
            console.log(resolveAllData)
          }
        });

Comment: when I do console.log(resoloveAllData), it says length is 0, but if I do console.log(promises) then I get 0: Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(1)}
1: Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(1)}
2: Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(1)}
3: Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(1)}
4: Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(1)}
5: Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(1)}
6: Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(1)}
7: Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(1)}
8: Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(1)}
9: Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(1)}
10: Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(1)}
length: 11
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: Look at the change I made in the code, the error was that 'promises.all' was out of search, when you run 'promises.all' it has no object
Also for be clear look this example: 
`
const promises = [];
let count = 0;

const asyncAction = text => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({ id: ++count, name: text });
    }, []);
  });
};

/**Loop  */
const text = ['hola', 'hello'];
for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  promises.push(asyncAction(text[i]));
}

Promise.all(promises).then(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
`